# Batch file to kill inactive sessions and programs

Tags: batch-file

Hi can any one help me in scheduling a job to kill all the inactive programs of the users who are inactive or the programs which are inactive for certain time.

Comment: it is unclear what user or program should be considered inactive

Comment: onservers users use some programs like sql developper and other applications and donot close the sessions after the usage I would like to terminate those sessions after th user doesn't use it for 60 min or so

Comment: I need this script as the users closes the session with out closing the open programs they will still be open on server which causes a lot of instances causing CPU usage issues.

Comment: what os, how they connect, what admin tools are used. not enough info. if this pure windows server with RDP, there is no need in batch file, it,s achieved by policies. and question sound like one for superuser stack, not for SO